# Binary vector counting

Tags: combinatorics

What is the count of all vectors $ \hat a \in B^{11}$, for which $|\hat a|$  = 5 and $ \mathcal v( \hat a ) > 2^5$?

where

$ B^{11} $ - all binary vectors with length 11

$|\hat a|$ - the sum of all binary vector coordinates (sum of 1s)

$ \mathcal v( \hat a )$ - decimal representation of the binary vector $ \hat a $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Compute the number of $\hat a$ with $|\hat a|=5$ and $v(\hat a)\le 2^5$; which positions of $\hat a$ have to be zero for the latter condition to be satisfied?